# Mingw64 / Msys2 - gcc unable to find headers in its own include dir

Tags: c, gcc, include, mingw-w64, msys2

I recently installed MSYS2 following *Steely Wing*'s answer on this thread: [How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

The final goal is to compile a project on Windows in order to create an executable that I can use with an installer.

But here comes the problem: when I use make, gcc does not find err.h:

```
src/debug/error_handler.c:2:10: fatal error: err.h: No such file or directory
        2 | #include <err.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~  
compilation terminated.  
make: *** [Makefile:26: imagin] Interrupt
```

After some searching I found out that it could come from the MinGW's default Include path. Thus following this: http://mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO, I created an empty foo.c and executed gcc -v foo.c:

```
Configured with: ../gcc-9.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-plugin --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT foo.c -quiet -dumpbase foo.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase foo -version -o C:\msys64\tmp\ccXlDSUc.s
GNU C17 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) version 9.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.21-GMP

warning: GMP header version 6.1.2 differs from library version 6.2.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) version 9.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.21-GMP

warning: GMP header version 6.1.2 differs from library version 6.2.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 3bcdf03344e3ad7cb057c2ec82f696e6
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\msys64\tmp\cckgYpTe.o C:\msys64\tmp\ccXlDSUc.s
GNU assembler version 2.33.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.33.1
COMPILER_PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\msys64\tmp\cch1aQIi.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -m i386pep -Bdynamic C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../.. C:\msys64\tmp\cckgYpTe.o -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/default-manifest.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/crtend.o
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
D:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is a bit messy but I think the interesting part is there:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
```

Considering the fact that err.h comes from openssl that I installed using https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl, openssl folder is included in /mingw64/include. But gcc does not find it.

I tried to use -I/mingw64/include in my CFLAGS, but it did not work. I tried with -I/mingw64/include/openssl and it worked, but now gcc considers errx function as unititialized, as if, before, gcc never went in the openssl folder. I tried to add -L/mingw64/lib but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated, thank's by advance. DO NOT hesitate to ask for any precision I could have miss here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Some additional details might be useful, indeed. What code are you trying to compile? And what (full) command do you use for it? A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be handy.

Comment: @jacob Thank you! I'm trying to compile a whole project so I won't post the entire code here. Here is the command provided by my Makefile:
```gcc -o main src/all/my/.c -W -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -Werror -O3 -lm  \
        `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs libtiff-4` \
        `pkg-config --cflags --libs libjpeg` `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml-2.0` \
        `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpng` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gexiv2` ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching I found out that there was no `err.h` on MSYS2, see https://github.com/cliffordwolf/icestorm/issues/85 and resolved my case by replacing all my `errx()` function calls following these method https://github.com/cliffordwolf/icestorm/pull/88/commits/9acaac752ac53b51b9b33290394b7811048221fa.

Comment: `#define errx(errcode, ...) do { fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); exit(errcode); } while (0)`